# Recursion question: Create array where each letter occupies an index of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am using javascript.

I am new to recursive functions, and cannot seem to figure out how to express this logic recursively:

" Write a function that accepts a string and creates an array where each letter
// occupies an index of the array. "

(Firstly,) I think the question is asking me to do the following:

'Hello' -> ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];

It is simple enough, but nothing I try seems to be working. I thought the base call could be :

```
function createArr(str) {

let results = [];
if (str.length === 0) { 
return results; 
}
```

and then I would recursively return the last letters of the string, and push them out once the stack is returned, like so:

```
else { 
var letters = createArr(str.slice(str.length-1)) 
results.push(letters);
return results;
}
}

console.log(createArr('Hello'));
```

But for some reason nothing seems to be working .. I would really appreciate if someone could clarify this problem for me.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion with array spread, to create an array, and flatten the results to a single array:

```js
function createArr(str) {
  if(!str.length) return []; // return an empty array when the string is empty
  
  return [
    str[0], // take the current letter
    ...createArr(str.slice(1)) // pass the rest of the string to createArr
  ]
}

console.log(createArr('Hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var createArray = function(str) {
  var resultArray = [];
  if (str.length === 1) {
    resultArray = resultArray.concat(str);
    return resultArray;
  }

  resultArray = resultArray.concat(str[0]);

  return resultAray = resultArray.concat(createArray(str.slice(1)));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can simply use `split` passing an empty string to perform that operation...
That aside if you wanted to solve this using recursion you can simply pass the result back into the function each time. e.g.

```js
// using split
function createArr1(s) {
   return s.split('')
}

console.log(createArr1('hello'))

// using recursion
function createArr2(s, out = []) {
    if(!s) return out;
    out.push(s[0]);
    return createArr2(s.slice(1), out);
}

console.log(createArr2('hello'))
```